# How to import mysql tables with data through odbc and vb.net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i am working with data that needs updated from a third party source. My problem is that i need to allow my program to automatically do this from an odbc connection. i get the error;

it is a very large file but it will fit into a string. The sql query will create tables and data. it is from a data dump.

```
Dim oOpen As New OpenFileDialog
Dim oSqlCreate As New MySqlConnections
dim oSqlConn As Odbc.OdbcConnection
Dim osqlcmd As New Odbc.OdbcCommand
Dim sr As StreamReader
Dim sql As String
Dim newFile As String
    oSqlConn = oSqlCreate.OpenEstConn()
    osqlcmd.Connection = oSqlConn
    oOpen.DefaultExt = ".sql"
    If oOpen.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.OK Then Exit Sub
        Try
            sr = New StreamReader(oOpen.FileName)
            newFile = sr.ReadToEnd()
            sql = "drop database VCDB"
            osqlcmd.CommandText = sql
            osqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sql = "Create database VCDB"
            osqlcmd.CommandText = sql
            osqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Drop or Create failed with the following error:" & ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try



newFile = "use VCDB; " & newFile
osqlcmd.CommandText = newFile
'error below
osqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


GetVersions()

MsgBox("Import Complete.")
```

Error code:

```
System.InvalidOperationException HResult=0x80131509 Message=The connection has been disabled. Source=System.Data Inner Exception 1: OdbcException: ERROR [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.19]MySQL server has gone away
```

Comment: it would not let me post the error code for some reason quite frustrating so here is the error code 'System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The connection has been disabled.
  Source=System.Data
 
Inner Exception 1:
OdbcException: ERROR [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.19]MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Added the error code for you.

Comment: thanks. Maybe this will be easier to answer. ho do i run a sql script from an odbc connection. i need to import these tables without user interaction.  I tried to send it to a stored procedure but it has "Lock" command and this is not allowed in stored procedures. I just need to get this mysql dump to import.

Comment: why do you not check the cenection if it is open? or for that matter if it is failed.

Comment: Hm my odbc is somewhat rusty, but usually you use   ODBC.NET and select the right provider and for that you install the odbc driver for mysql.

Comment: i need to clarify, i have no trouble connecting, and i have routines in other classes that handle connection failure. My problem is that the sql statements contain allot of data. i have found a partial fix by changing the buffer size in the my.ini file

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size =128k but now the error i am getting errors in defining variables. the sql command must not allow this, so my next step was to  send it to an stored procedure but lock command is not allowed in a stored procedure. so i am stuck unless i interact with the .sql file in the workbench i cannot get it to import.  If there is some method possibly using dts package like in sql server.

Comment: These three lines really confuse me. `Dim oSqlCreate As New MySqlConnection` 
        `Dim oSqlConn As Odbc.OdbcConnection` and 
       `oSqlConn = oSqlCreate.OpenEstConn()`. What does a `MySqlConnection` have to do with a `ODBCConnection`? What is `OpenEstConn()`? Is this some kind of extension method of a  `MySqlConnection` that creates a `New ODBCConnection`?

Answer (score 0):

I see it happening more like this.

```
Private Sub DropAndCreateDB()
    Using cn As New OdbcConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OdbcCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "Drop Database VCDB"
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.CommandText = "Create database VCDB"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    CreateTablesAndAddData()
End Sub

Private Sub CreateTablesAndAddData()
    Using cn As New OdbcConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OdbcCommand("use VCDB; " & ReadFile(), cn)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Function ReadFile() As String
    Dim oOpen As New OpenFileDialog
    oOpen.DefaultExt = ".sql"
    Return File.ReadAllText(oOpen.FileName)
End Function
```

If there are statements that are not to the liking of ODBC in the file then that is another issue and we would need to see some sample content of the file.

Comment: my code is working fine it is the fact that sql is choking on some of the commands, it will not allow variable decoration in the sql statements. i have modified the connection to allow multiple statements per sql command. If i can get past the variable declaration errors we would be fine. Mind you this .sql file works fine in the workbench.